# I am trying to Dismiss progressbar from my service but its shows error

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I am trying to  Dismiss Progress-bar from service but shows force close error.
I have created progressbar in main activity for startservice onclick button 
and than i want to dismiss it on prepare listener for mediaplyer.
As we cannot write ui functions in service i write it into activity.
I also tried Main_acitivty object . pregressbar.dismiss();
but it shows force close error.
Any good solution for this problem.

Edited :- I got progressbar but when on prepare is done and media player is about to start i get force close error because of this line i think 
"vm.progressDialog.dismiss();"
 play();

Answer :- I import the activity into service and in activity i made progressbar to static one and it works fine.

Here is my service and media-player is initialized

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {


 mp = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        showNoti();
        final Main vm = new Main();


        mp.setDataSource(link);
        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mp.prepareAsync();

        mp.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                vm.progressDialog.dismiss();
                mp.start();
                b=true;
            }
        });

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Error

```
09-17 18:12:01.330: E/AndroidRuntime(6708): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-17 18:12:01.330: E/AndroidRuntime(6708): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-17 18:12:01.330: E/AndroidRuntime(6708): at com.android.twitter.myPlayService$1.onPrepared(myPlayService.java:53)
09-17 18:12:01.330: E/AndroidRuntime(6708): at android.media.MediaPlayer$EventHandler.handleMessage(MediaPlayer.java:1973)
09-17 18:12:01.330: E/AndroidRuntime(6708): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-17 18:12:01.330: E/AndroidRuntime(6708): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
```

Comment: what's the error? post the stacktrace

Comment: I have added logcat into main post

Comment: Well, NullPointerException...Are you sure your MediaPlayer instance has been initialized?

Comment: Yup its initialized you can take a look at my service

Comment: I solved it By importing main activity into service and I have make my progressdialog to static so it works fine.

Comment: place if(vm!=null) then vm.progressDialog.dismiss() in onPrepared;

Answer (score 0):

The better solution would be to have your progress bar inside activity only and register a `BroadcastReceiver` which dismisses progress bar.

Inside service:

```
  mp.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent();
         intent.setAction("dismiss_progress_dialog");
       sendBroadcast(intent);

            mp.start();
            b=true;
        }
    });
```

Inside activity

```
 class MyBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent i) {


                progressDialog.dismiss();

            }
        };

  MyBroadcast receiver;
```

Inside onResume activity:

```
    receiver=new MyBroadcast();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("dismiss_progress_dialog");

    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

Inside onPause:

```
   unregisterReceiver(receiver);
```